# Get Lat & Lng from GeoDjango OSMGeoAdmin

Tags: openlayers-2, geodjango

Django OSMGeoAdmin with PointField uses OpenLayers and it's hard to use.

I want to add two new input elements which are lat and lng. Using jQuery, when values of the input elements are changed, I want to change point on the OpenLayers.

How can I do that?

No complete code or instructions are necessary, main idea is enough.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know is there any difference with geodjando and OSMGeoAdmin but in normal geodjango if you want to update any field, you can use following code:

```
def updateVal(request):
  poId = request.POST.get("pointID", default=0)
  objGeo = request.POST.get("meta", default=0)

  f = Points.objects.get(id = poId)

  try:
      f.geom = objGeo 
      f.save()
      res = "OK"
  except:
      res = "ERROR"
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thank You! but I want to do that in browser side.

Comment: You could pass an argument to this from the browser using an ajax request.